# Pattern Replacement Query.

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Currently I have

```
 Input: e.g., '123456789'.'+'.'987654321'
```

Desired Pattern:

```
Output: e.g., '123456789987654321'
```

How can I achieve this using in php  ? I am not through on regex and so what regex would go in preg_replace for this ?

Comment: I have modified now, Input is of mentioned pattern and desired output is of other pattern and so what regex could solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have `"123456789+987654321"` as the input and want `"123456789987654321"` as the output, you'd just have to remove the `"+"` No need for regex:

```
$output = str_replace("+", "", $input);
```

If you want to replace this pattern in a bigger string, you can use this regex:

```
$output = preg_replace("/(\\d+)\\+(\\d+)/", "$1$2", $input);
```

Note that the "+" has a special meaning in regex and needs to be escaped by a backslash. Additionally, the backslash has a special meaning in PHP strings and needs to be escaped by a backslash *itself*.

So the above turns into the in-memory string `/(\d+)\+(\d+)/`, and the regex engine can understand that you mean multiple digits (`\d+`) and a literal plus (`\+`).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question, but if you're asking how to get rid of the plus symbol:

```
$input = '123456789+987654321';
$output = preg_replace('/([^+]+)\+([^+]+)/', '$1$2', $input);
echo $output, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Input is in the form '123456789'.'+'.'987654321' and so current regex wont give desired result.

Comment: `'123456789'.'+'.'987654321'` is the same as `'123456789+987654321'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you explain the regex used, so I can learn some about regexes ?

Comment: he's looking for the actually quote "'123456789'.'+'.'987654321'"

Comment: @St.John Johnson: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 $input = "'123456789'.'+'.'987654321'";
 $output = trim("'", preg_replace("/([^+]+)'\.'\+'\.'([^+]+)/", "$1$2", $input));
 // Without RegEx
 $output = trim("'", str_replace("'.'+'.'", "", $input));
 echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he's actually trying to concatenate

```
 $customer_id = 123456789;
 $operator_domain = 987654321;

 $Output = $customer_id.$operator_domain;
```

Comment: Yes. But am not getting two strings seperately, I have string1+string2 and I want to concatenate it to string1string2